# How to overwrite jquery ui-datepicker style?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

We are using ui-datepicker on an old system. It is setting the component style by adding to the div a style , for example

```
<div id="ui-datepicker-div" class="ui-corner-all ui-datepicker ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget ui-widget-content" style="left: 1078px; position: absolute; top: 316px; z-index: 100; display: block;">
```

How can we overwrite the added style (its not working in mobile ...)

Comment: Please explain your problem bit more.

Comment: the site is http://baco.co.il/ when the datepicker is open in mobile its on the  right and hidden I want to put it on the left. Here is an image when its ok (not mobile ) http://prntscr.com/evjnx5

Comment: for this you need to write your inline css in head tag then only you can overwrite it.

Comment: didn't work  http://prntscr.com/evjsqw

Comment: did you remove from inline??

Comment: what do you mean by inline ? put it directly in the html and not on separate css ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141558/discussion-between-user1726407-and-hirenmangukiya).

Comment: i mean remove your `css` from `div` and try again.

Answer (score 0):

> How can we overwrite the added style

One way to override inline styles is to use `!important` on every property/value on your external CSS style sheet.

```
#ui-datepicker-div{
   left: 1078px !important; 
   position: absolute !important; 
   top: 316px !important;
   ....
   ....
}
```

then just include all the other necessary property/value pairs.

Comment: I tried that ,,, didn't work - I assume that the js inside datepicker is putting the style each time the window is open

Comment: @user1726407 yeah, that's also a possibility but then I would consider other solutions because this is the typical way to override inline styles.

Answer (score 0):

I also came across this issue so posting my solution for future users:

The style attribute is added dynamically after page load when the datepicker object is triggered therefore any style attributes assigned to "#ui-datepicker-div" are over-written, with or without "!important".

My work around was to re-assign my styling after the datepicker is triggered:

```
        $('#date').click(function () {
            $("#ui-datepicker-div").css('z-index', '9999');
        });
```

In my case the element with ID date is clicked to show the datepicker object. Hope this helps!